# Not able to open Azure SQL Server DB immidiately after the creation

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sql-database

I am trying to automate the tenant DB creation in Azure SQL Server.
DB has been created/copied as

```
CREATE DATABASE {0} AS COPY OF {1} ( SERVICE_OBJECTIVE = 'S2' )
```

Immediately adding a record to one of the table in the same. Getting error as:

> Function completed (Failure, Id=1046eae2-c07a-4eee-9a1d-886e89ab5071)
>   A ScriptHost error has occurred
>   Exception while executing function: Functions.CreateTenant. .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Database 'tenant8' on server 'dbserver' is not currently available.  Please retry the connection later.  If the problem persists, contact customer support, and provide them the session tracing ID of '8AF58081-8F25-4B7F-83E3-63AFFC13C8CB'.
>   Exception while executing function: Functions.CreateTenant
>   Executed 'Functions.CreateTenant' (Failed, Id=1046eae2-c07a-4eee-9a1d-886e89ab5071)
>     Function had errors. See Azure WebJobs SDK dashboard for details. Instance ID is '1046eae2-c07a-4eee-9a1d-886e89ab5071'

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error message, it seems that you are trying to insert data before the database `tenant8` has been provisioned and deployed. Deploying a database takes any time between a few dozens seconds to a few minutes. A description of the steps involved in this operation can be found on this [blog post](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/what-happens-when-you-deploy-on-windows-azure) by Steve Mark. Please let us know if the deployment takes more than 5 minutes.